# How to manage resource in Android

Tags: java, android, performance

Hi i just start wonder what is better. Always load small data from resources (like dimension, color etc.) or load once when it's neede and put it on some HasMap.

- I have grid layout. Size : 7*7 so i have 49 items.
- Every item have special date like: color, dimension, some drawable, some font size.
- This is a representation of single level. So when user passed level 1, before start level 2 everything is loaded from resources again.

So my question is:

What is better?

1) Always load data from resources.
2) Load data from resources when it's needed. Put this data to HasMap and when we need this resource again, load from this HasMap instead of load from resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how many times you are accessing the resources for eg; if by moving from level 1 to level 2, you are not allowing user to go back to level 1, then it is advised to use resources only, but if there are frequent movements between level 1 and level 2, then storing them in hashmap, would be good, because you would have the hashmaps already ready to be used somewhere.

Comment: No, I'm not allowing user to go back to level 1 form level 2. But User can go play and go form level 1 to for example level 100. Why you think that "it is advised to use resources only" is better than use HashMap?

Comment: no that is what I said, if the user can move frequently in between levels, then you should use hashmap, but if that level is accessible only once or maybe twice then direct access would be much more preferable because hashmaps use system resources

Comment: What do you mean that hasmaps use system resources? You think that in this situation is better to load data allways from resources?

Comment: hashmaps keep data on ram and will be stored like that for the lifetime of the program, on the other hand resources are bundled inside app.